# How to get preprocessed output of header file alone?

Tags: android, linux, c-preprocessor

I have a header file, where in I have used like:

```
#if defined(LINUX) || defined(ANDROID)
 pthread_t gpthread;
 #endif
```

Now, I would like to get only the header file content after passing -DLINUX in the compilation. Is there any way to get it ?  If I use:

```
#arm-linux-androideabi-g++ -E main.c > temp
```

then the output is bit confusing to me.

Comment: Care to explain what you mean with "confusing"?

Comment: What prevented you from creating a .c file which has only this header file included in it and getting the preprocessed output of the same? Am I missing something? It should give you the desired output. : )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just ask the compiler to do the preprocessing only on the header file:

```
arm-linux-androideabi-g++ -DLINUX -E foo.h > temp
```

Answer (score 4):

You might be interested in keeping comments in the preprocessed output (to enhance readability) with

```
 arm-linux-androideabi-g++ -DLINUX -C -E foo.h > foo.i
```

then look (with an editor or a pager) into `foo.i`

The generated `foo.i` contains lines starting with a `#` to convey location information.

Comment: I use this method to preprocess headers for ffi on lua and luajit

Answer (score 0):

Why not call `cpp -D<something to be defined> <header file name>` directly?